# HTML Tags are not rendered properly - Read text file- worpdress

Tags: wordpress, function

I've created a function that reads a textfile. The content is placed in a post

**Post**

[drawSQL file="exercise1" dir="sql/chapter01"]

**Function**

```
    function drawSQL($file, $subDirectory) {

        $content = file_get_contents("http://mydomein.com/$file.sql\"");

echo do_shortcode('<PRE lang=\"tsql\" class=\"attributes\">'. $content .'</PRE>');

    }

    function drawSQLHook( $atts ) {

        if ( isset($atts['file']) && isset($atts['dir'])){
            drawSQL($atts['file'], $atts['dir']);
        }

    }
    add_shortcode( 'drawSQL', 'drawSQLHook' );
```

The pre-tags are used to format the content (textfile).

The content is shown without the format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution my self:

```
echo apply_filters('the_content', '[sql]'. $content .'[/sql]'  );
```